# Hibernate Ehcache Operations and Event Handlers

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, event-handling, ehcache

I currently have my application integrated with Hibernate. It saves/retrieves data from the database successfully. Next, I would like to configure ehcache such that my application does not have to hit the database every time.

That being said, I was wondering if there are any ehcache event handlers that would allow me to run some custom piece of code before (or after) a cache operation (i.e. put, remove, get, etc.)?

Also, when my application is about to save a DAO, my understanding is hibernate will push that to the database. What I would like to know whether the db operation will be performed before, during or after the event handler (above) is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a `CacheEventListener` which would allow you to receive notifications of put/update/remove events - and then you could perform some action accordingly. The notification occurs after the event has happened.

You configure a listener in the `ehcache.xml` file on a per-cache basis:

```
<cache ...>
  <cacheEventListenerFactory class="your.listener.FactoryClass" />
  ...
</cache>
```

Where the `cacheEventListenerFactory` is a class that you create which in turn creates your listener. See [the EHCache docs](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners) for more detailed info.

For integration of EHCache with Hibernate, you should look at the `EhCacheRegionFactory`. Again see [the docs](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.5/integrations/hibernate#Configure-Ehcache-as-the-Second-Level-Cache-Provider) for step by step instructions of how this is set up.

Comment: Just to add on to what Will answered, in regards to when "the db operation will be performed" in relation to the cache operation that depends.  Specifically it depends on the "access type" (org.hibernate.cache.spi.access.AccessType) in use.  I am not certain that any Ehcache second-level cache providers support "transactional access" which is the main outlier in this regard.  So what *should* happen is that you see 2 puts on the underlying cache: the first "locks" the data; the second updates the data and releases the lock.